# JavaFX navigationbar and contentpane

Tags: java, javafx, navigationbar, contentpane

I want to use JavaFX in my new project and want something like in the screenshot below.

On the left site I need a navigation bar and on the right my content. So, I would use a VBox on the left side and maybe an AnchorPane on the right side (or better a ScrollPane).

And when I click on the Button "Security" it should load my "Security" Scene on the right side. But how can I manage that. Did not find any solution for this.

[image]

Thanks a lot

Comment: What have you tried to code yourself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an exemplary implementation of such navigation. Here the view described in `view_1.fxml` is loaded by default:

```
<BorderPane fx:id="mainBorderPane" fx:controller="sample.Controller" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <left>
        <VBox spacing="5">
            <Button text="btn 1" onAction="#handleShowView1"/>
            <Button text="btn 2" onAction="#handleShowView2"/>
            <Button text="btn 3" onAction="#handleShowView3"/>
        </VBox>
    </left>
    <center>
        <fx:include source="view_1.fxml"/>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

And this is the controller

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private BorderPane mainBorderPane;

    @FXML
    private void handleShowView1(ActionEvent e) {
        loadFXML(getClass().getResource("/sample/view_1.fxml"));
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleShowView2(ActionEvent e) {
        loadFXML(getClass().getResource("/sample/view_2.fxml"));
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleShowView3(ActionEvent e) {
        loadFXML(getClass().getResource("/sample/view_3.fxml"));
    }

    private void loadFXML(URL url) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(url);
            mainBorderPane.setCenter(loader.load());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**update**

This is a conversion in which the views are listed directly in the FXML file

```
<BorderPane fx:id="mainBorderPane" fx:controller="sample.Controller" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <left>
        <VBox spacing="5">
            <Button text="btn 1" userData="/sample/view_1.fxml" onAction="#handleShowView"/>
            <Button text="btn 2" userData="/sample/view_2.fxml" onAction="#handleShowView"/>
            <Button text="btn 3" userData="/sample/view_3.fxml" onAction="#handleShowView"/>
        </VBox>
    </left>
    <center>
        <fx:include source="view_1.fxml"/>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

and controller

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private BorderPane mainBorderPane;

    @FXML
    private void handleShowView(ActionEvent e) {
        String view = (String) ((Node)e.getSource()).getUserData();
        loadFXML(getClass().getResource(view));
    }

    private void loadFXML(URL url) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(url);
            mainBorderPane.setCenter(loader.load());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```