# Switching between different scenes with their own fxml and controllers

Tags: java, javafx, scene

I'm trying to program a GUI in *javafx 12*. Basically I'd like a main stage parent which has its own fxml and controller that has only a menu bar, I'd like to fill up the space under the menu bar with a different scene chosen dynamically based on the user choice. The different scenes have their own fxml and controller as well. How can I change only a portion of the main stage scene?

To be clear: what I don't want to do is putting the exact same menu bar with same functionality in 2 different scenes if this can be avoided. This is the code I've written so far:

[image]

```
class MainStage {

    private String mainstagefxml ="/soluzione/MainStage.fxml";


    public MainStage() {

    }

    public void display(int view, boolean opt) throws IOException {
        Stage mainstage = new Stage();
        MainStageController cntrl = new MainStageController(view, opt);
        mainstage.setOnShowing(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent wev) {
                ChooseWindow chooser = new ChooseWindow();
                try {
                    chooser.display(mainstage);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }               
            }

        });
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setController(cntrl);    
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(mainstagefxml));
        mainstage.setTitle("Emotional Maps");
        mainstage.setScene(loader.load());
        mainstage.show();

    }


}

public class MainStageController implements Initializable{

    private String basicfxml = "/soluzione/basicView.fxml";
    private String debugfxml = "/soluzione/debugView.fxml";
    private int viewType;
    private boolean opt;



    public MainStageController(int viewType, boolean opt) {
        this.viewType = viewType;
        this.opt = opt;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
         *In here code to set view according to viewType value passed*

    }

    public int getViewType() {
        return viewType;
    }

    public void setViewType(int viewType) {
        this.viewType = viewType;
    }

    public boolean isOpt() {
        return opt;
    }

    public void setOpt(boolean opt) {
        this.opt = opt;
    }


}
```

**MainStage fxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <MenuBar layoutY="2.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>

   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

UPDATE: Following the suggestion I've added the method insertPane into my MainController, here is the code:

```
public class MainStageController implements Initializable{

private String basicfxml = "/soluzione/basicView.fxml";
private String debugfxml = "/soluzione/debugView.fxml";
private int viewType;
private boolean opt;

@FXML AnchorPane anchorPane;

public MainStageController(int viewType, boolean opt) {
    this.viewType = viewType;
    this.opt = opt;
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    if (viewType == 1) {
        insertPane(basicfxml, anchorPane, new BasicController(), null);
    } else if (viewType == 2) {
        insertPane(debugfxml, anchorPane, new DebugController(), null);
    }

}

public int getViewType() {
    return viewType;
}

public void setViewType(int viewType) {
    this.viewType = viewType;
}

public boolean isOpt() {
    return opt;
}

public void setOpt(boolean opt) {
    this.opt = opt;
}

private void insertPane(String fxmlFileName, AnchorPane parent, Initializable controller, String cssFileName) {
    try {
        URL fxmlUrl = getClass().getResource(fxmlFileName);
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(fxmlUrl);
        fxmlLoader.setController(controller);
        Parent pane = fxmlLoader.load();
        if (cssFileName != null) {
            pane.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource(cssFileName).toExternalForm());
        }
        parent.getChildren().add(pane);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(pane, 0d);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(pane, 0d);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(pane, 0d);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(pane, 0d);
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now when I try to run the application several errors occur:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: Controller value already specified.
/C:/Users/Giuly/eclipse-workspace/EmotionalMaps/bin/soluzione/basicView.fxml:7

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2621)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:922)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:980)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:227)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:752)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
    at soluzione.MainStageController.insertPane(MainStageController.java:60)
    at soluzione.MainStageController.initialize(MainStageController.java:32)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2573)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
    at soluzione.MainStage.display(MainStage.java:39)
    at soluzione.WelcomeController.confirm_selection(WelcomeController.java:55)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1782)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8890)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3862)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2590)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:299)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:447)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:446)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1787)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8890)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3862)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2590)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:299)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:447)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:446)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1782)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane cannot be cast to class javafx.scene.Scene (javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane and javafx.scene.Scene are in module javafx.graphics of loader 'app')
    at soluzione.MainStage.display(MainStage.java:39)
    at soluzione.WelcomeController.confirm_selection(WelcomeController.java:55)
    ... 57 more
```

Line 39 of MainStage.java is:

```
mainstage.setScene(loader.load());
```

My guess is that this line of code in the method I've added is raising the exception:

```
parent.getChildren().add(pane);
```

but honestly I'm not sure

---

UPDATE 2: PROBLEM SOLVED!

Fixed the problem caused by line 39 with this simple fix:

```
Scene mainscene = new Scene(loader.load());
    mainstage.setScene(mainscene);
    mainstage.show();
```

Everything works fine, thanks to everybody!

Comment: look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48019690/javafx-navigationbar-and-contentpane/48023584#48023584 the principle is the same.

Comment: https://github.com/sedj601/RestaurantOrdersDuplicateFX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one of the scenes in the main stage and if needed remove the stage and put in the other stage. You can use a method like this one:

```
private void insertPane(String fxmlFileName, AnchorPane parent, Initializable controller, String cssFileName) {
    try {
        URL fxmlUrl = getClass().getResource(fxmlFileName);
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(fxmlUrl);
        fxmlLoader.setController(controller);
        Parent pane = fxmlLoader.load();
        if (cssFileName != null) {
            pane.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource(cssFileName).toExternalForm());
        }
        parent.getChildren().add(pane);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(pane, 0d);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(pane, 0d);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(pane, 0d);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(pane, 0d);
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This method (that goes in your main stage's controller class) will load an fxml file, it's controller and optionally a css file and put it in the `parent` AnchorPane.

Therefore you sould add an `AnchorPane` to the main stage to which the scenes can be added. And you should remove the last scene from the AnchorPane before adding a new one, using the method `getChildren().clear()` on the `parent` AnchorPane.

Comment: This is awsome thank you! Though I get several errors when I try to run the application, here is the print stack trace

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is without knowing the code that produced the error. Maybe it's better to start a new question on this. Or edit your question and add the code that throws the exception and the stacktrace.

Comment: *Controller value already specified.* this exception is thrown by `fxmlLoader.setController` and the reason is that it already has a specified controller with the `fx:controller` directive.

Comment: I've updated the question with new code. So for the Controller already specified do I need to delete the controller in the fxml file?

Comment: You could either remove the controller from the fxml file or remove the controller in the `insertPane` method, by removing the line `fxmlLoader.setController(controller);`. So the controller is set only once. Both solutions should have the same effect, I think.

Comment: That worked thanks, still the classCastException persists, trying to find answers on other threads but no luck yet

Comment: `mainstage.setScene` most likely accepts an instance of `Scene` but you pass as a parameter the value returned by `loader.load()` which is an instance of `AnchorPane`.

Comment: To fix the `ClassCastException` you need to wrap the `AnchorPane` in a Scene like htis: `Parent root = loader.load();` `Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1200, 800);` `mainstage.setScene(scene);`

Comment: @mrmcwolf Thank you! That fixed all the problems I honestly didn't notice the mistake. Everything works fine, I'm going to post the solution in the original post. Again thank you everyone!